# Keycloak exctract users with TOTP Config

Tags: export, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, totp

I use Keycloak in my company, and I have it on two environments one of test & one of production. I would need to extract the list of my users from one of my production realms. `

So I did it with the command: `bin / kc.sh export --dir / data / keycloak-21.0.1 / data / export / --users different_files --users-per-file 100 --realm TEST_REALM`

I therefore export my users well, however the users of this realm have a configured connection with TOTP and use a physical card which has been configured before. The export shows that the users have a TOTP config with the argument `" totp ": true,` but to the reimportation of the users, the config which was carried out must be redone. When a user connects for the first time, they are asked to reconfigure their card, but users cannot do it by themselves and we cannot recover all the cards to make this configuration.

It is also possible to export this configuration to replicate it on the import user without having to perform this configuration again?